# Javascript Custom Price Calculator

Tags: javascript

I have this below code to calculate a custom price based upon selection. It works for stretched canvas, but i was wondering how to make it work for other options if a user selects it. (e.g Canvas Boards). If option equals "Canvas Boards" calculate custom price. Many thanks, Deryn.

```js
 function calculate_total() {
     var ttl = 0;
     var len = eval(document.forms['calc']['length'].value);
     var wid = eval(document.forms['calc']['width'].value);
     var thick = document.forms['calc']['frame'].value;
     var strOptions = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
     if(len.length == 0) {
         return;
     }
     if(wid.length == 0) {
         return;
     }
     if(thick == 0) {
         return;
     }
     ttl = (len + wid) * 2;
     //inches
     if((ttl >= 24) && (ttl <= 36)) {
         ttl *= .19;
     }
     if((ttl >= 37) && (ttl <= 56)) {
         ttl *= .20;
     }
     if((ttl >= 57) && (ttl <= 76)) {
         ttl *= .21;
     }
     if((ttl >= 77) && (ttl <= 92)) {
         ttl *= .22;
     }
     if((ttl >= 93) && (ttl <= 100)) {
         ttl *= .23;
     }
     switch(thick) {
     case "1.5":
         ttl;
         break;
     case "2":
         ttl;
         break;
     case "3":
         ttl;
         break;
     }
     document.getElementById('total').value = ttl.toFixed(2);
 } // end function definition
```

```html
<form name="calc" id="calc">
    Length: <input type="text" name="length" id="length" onchange="calculate_total()" /> Inches <br />
    Width: <input type="text" name="width" id="width" onchange="calculate_total()" /> Inches <br />

    <select name="frame" onchange="calculate_total()">
        <option value="0" selected>Select below</option>
        <option value="1.5">Streched Canvas</option>
        <option value="2">Canvas Boards</option>
        <option value="3">Canvas Rolls</option>
        <option value="4">Primed Boards</option>
        <option value="5">Paintings/Printing Streching</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <b>Total:</b> $ <input id="total" name="total" readonly=true style="border: none" />
</form>
```

Comment: Be careful calculating pricing in JavaScript unless you also have server-side validation. It is very easily hacked.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  How do you want the calculation to differ for each option?

Comment: Hi Gilly, thank you for your reply. For each of the dropdown options i would like it to calculate a custom price. I've done a big (kinda messy) if statement for 'stretched canvas'. So if Canvas Boards selected calculate custom price.

Comment: @deryn - Yes, that makes sense, by it doesn't answer my question.  I understand that the prices should differ per option.  What I don't know is *how* the prices should differ.  Eg, will there be a different price per inch for each option?

Comment: Hi Gilly, thank you again for your reply. There will be a different price per inch for each option :) The .20, .20, .23 etc is a price variable for stretched canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Complete edit:

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPj4K/21/)

In the link provided above, you can see the example, with other function for every option picked from the list. For now they just shows alert window, but you should know what to put there, to count it.

```
function check_which_selected() {
    selectedOption = document.forms['calc']['frame'].options;
    thick = +selectedOption[selectedOption.selectedIndex].value;
    ttl = 0;
    len = +document.forms['calc']['length'].value;
    wid = +document.forms['calc']['width'].value;

    if (len.length <= 0) return;
    if (wid.length <= 0) return;
    if (thick <= 0) return;

    if (thick == "0") return;
    if (thick == "1.5") calculate_total();
    if (thick == "2") calculate_total_canvas_boards();
    if (thick == "3") calculate_tota_canvas_rolls();
    if (thick == "4") calculate_total_primed_boards();
    if (thick == "5") calculate_total_paintings();
}
```

This function lets you check, what option is chosed, what values are put into text boxes. If some textbox is empty, or option is not picked, it wont call any function, otherwise, it will call proper function depending on the option chosed. Variables taken from tetboxes, are scoped for both of these function, so their value is assigned in `check_which_selected()` and then they can be used inside other functions.

You can also use your `switch/case` to define which function will be called.

Is that something you was looking for?

Comment: Hi Kedor, Sorry for the messy code. I have a function calculate_total() for streched canvas dropdown option, but i would like to create an identical function for Canvas Boards, Canvas Rolls etc. So each dropdown selection has a custom unique price

Comment: Hi all, thank you all for your assistance, much appreciated. What im try to do is calculate a custom price based upon selection. The calculate_total() function is to calculate the total price for streched canvases only. I was hoping to have a function for Canvas Boards, Canvas Rolls etc based on identical logic. (e.g calculate_total_CanvasBoards(), calculate_total_CanvasRolls() etc.

Comment: edited, check the example on jsfiddle, and check if thats solution you are looking for. Thats one of possible solutions ofc

Comment: Thanks guys, this is perfect :) Just wondering how it calculates the price. As ttl = (len + wid) * 2 = 96; so 96 is greater than 92, so price = 96 * .23 which equals $22.08. It says price is $1115.04. Many thanks, Deryn.

Comment: This is when I type in a length and width of 24

Comment: Fixed that. It was caused by my mistake. `wid = +document.forms['calc']['width'].value;` <-- "+" on the beginning now makes it take number, and without it it was treated as string, and it was a mistake, cuz `wid + len` wasn't a math sum, but joining the string.

Comment: Ah, forgot to add example: http://jsfiddle.net/JPj4K/21/ (it returns 22.08 as supposed now)

Comment: Hi guys, I have inches on the end of the textboxes, was wondering if its possible to convert inches to CM/CM to inches based on what a user enters in the textfields.

Comment: yes, it is possible. Simple make these inches a select list, with CM and inch option. Once some1 changes it, it simply changes the value in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you are learning JavaScript.  Keep at it!

Are you *sure* it's working for stretched boards?  I see some areas that can be improved, and others that are just plain broken.

First, you are referencing a variable, `e`, but that variable is never defined.  That will cause an error.  It looks like `e` is meant to refer to the `frame` selector.  But, since `e` is only used to create `strOptions`, and `strOptions` is never used, we can just delete that whole line and not even worry about `e`.

Next, the use of `eval` is discouraged, especially the way you intend to.  It looks like you are trying to get a number from a string.  Several points here:

- There are many easier, safer ways of turning a string into a number.  Personally, I'd just use the `+` operator to do it.  Eg, `var n = +"10"`.  `parseFloat()` is another good option.
- If the user does not enter a number, you will most likely get an error.  For example, if the user enters "n/a", `eval()` will try to interpret that as script.  Assuming `n` and `a` are not actual variable names, that will cause an error.  But actually, it could be valid JavaScript:  If you have variables `n` and `a` defined, and they are numbers, this actually will run and not return an error.  It *will* however give unexpected results - it will proceed as if the user entered the actual value that is `n` divided by `a`.
- The user can use your form to execute arbitrary script.  Try entering `alert("hello world")` into one of your form fields.  Of course, the user can also just use the address bar or the browser's JavaScript console to execute arbitrary script, so this isn't *really* a security hole, but still, you don't want that.

The way you are accessing your form is more verbose than you need.  Instead of:

```
document.forms['calc']['length'].value;
```

You can skip the square bracket notation and the reference to `forms`:

```
document.calc.length.value;
```

I'd go one further and just store a reference to `document.calc` in a variable:

```
var f = document.calc;
var len = +f.length.value;
var wid = +f.width.value;
var thick = +f.frame.value;
```

(Notice how I used `+` to get a number, as I mentioned earlier)

Guessing here, it looks like you are applying a discount with your `ttl *= .19` code, but it looks like you are applying it backwards.  Eg, the more canvas your user purchases the higher the cost per inch.  Shouldn't it be cheaper per inch the more you purchase?  You know, like breakfast cereal?

Either way, there are some flaws in the logic.  You are always using less than or equal to and greater than or equal to.  Never just plain less than or greater than.  So you are missing some values. If I enter length 5 and width 5, my price is $20.  But, if I enter length 6 and width 6 my prices is just $4.56.  If I enter 8 x 10, I get $6.84, but if I enter 8x10.25, I get $36.50.  That can't be right, can it?  Instead, do it like this:

```
if (ttl > 92) {
    ttl *= .23;
}
else if (ttl > 76) {
    ttl *= .22;
}
else if (ttl > 56) {
    ttl *= .21;
}
else if (ttl > 36) {
    ttl *= .20;
}
else {
    ttl *= .19;
}
```

Your `switch` statement does absolutely nothing.  You can just remove that whole code block.

Comment: But i guess he wanted to use `switch`, to change the outcome, depending on chosen option from select list. He didnt know how, and that's one part of his question.